# Как найти все слова, которые имеют только одну Заглавную букву в строке и не имеют числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

Нужна помощь с решением регулярных выражений.
Задача проста, нужно найти все слова, которые имеют только одну Заглавную букву в строке и не имеют числа.

Я пытался что-то вроде такого сделать, но безуспешно:

```
import re
pattern = r"\b\w[а-яА-ЯёЁ]\w+(?![0-9])\b"
result = re.findall(pattern, 'Яблоко яБлоко ябЛоко яблОко яблоКо яблокО яблоко7 яблоко')
print(result)
```

Я очень плохо понимаю как устроены регулярные выражения. Помогите решить задачу и объясните мне потом, пожалуйста, почему именно так нужно сделать.

Comment: в выводе должно быть следующее: Яблоко яБлоко ябЛоко яблОко яблоКо яблокО

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать регулярные выражения, установите библиотеку PyPi regex с помощью `pip install regex` используйте

```py
import regex
pattern = r"\b\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*\b"
text = 'Яблоко яБлоко ябЛоко яблОко яблоКо яблокО яблоко7 яблоко'
result = regex.findall(pattern, text)
print(result)
# => ['Яблоко', 'яБлоко', 'ябЛоко', 'яблОко', 'яблоКо', 'яблокО']
```

См. [пример выполнения кода](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqsgsaQktShPwVahSCkmKaag2ienVgtEldbCOElKXCWpFSVAJeoX1l/YeGH3hX0Xdl3Yp3Cx/8JEZM7GC7ORObsvzEPm7LswC5mz68I8ZM4@cxSeOldRanFpDshOsDP10jLzUhJzcjSgztVRALlIk6ugKDOvRAOiVvP/fwA).

Если регулярные выражения использовать необязательно, вы можете использовать

```py
import re, sys
uc_letters = [chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).isupper()]
text = 'Яблоко яБлоко ябЛоко яблОко яблоКо яблокО яблоко7 яблоко'
print( [slovo for slovo in text.split() if all(c.isalpha() for c in slovo) and len([c for c in slovo if c in uc_letters]) == 1 ] )
# => ['Яблоко', 'яБлоко', 'ябЛоко', 'яблОко', 'яблоКо', 'яблокО']
```

См. [пример кода](https://tio.run/##XZBNasMwEEb3PsW3iwTFULLoyicxpghFiQWKJCQ5JKco2SaQK4RsE/AZpidy/bOo2t085pvhzfhTap1dD4PeexcSgnpDPMWik59GpaRCRIVatoFpjq0L0NAWQdidYmOu3ItjZ7V0G8Wht1iCpY6d9yow3hRJHdO4YkV3etCLenpSj@8vOufwoGsOL7rl0NMlhyfdcug//tCq8EHbxFBH4w5udl6q0XuSKaM3OrFZVxjD5GgrjG8FWw6UU3Ce4BB2A6Msq@W/1nzrRL9/ajiqCu9owIfhBw).

*Подробности*:

- `uc_letters` - список всех заглавных букв Юникода
- `[slovo for slovo in text.split()...` - разбивает строку на слова по пробельным символам, а затем оставляет только те, которые
- `if all(c.isalpha() for c in slovo) and...` состоят целиком из букв и
- `len([c for c in slovo if c in uc_letters]) == 1 ]` в которых имеется только одна заглавная буква.